# Is there a way to turn the sound off of a Roomba?

Tags: irobot-create, roomba, digital-audio

I am working with an iRobot Create 2 and I work with others around me. Whenever I turn the robot on, send it an OI reset command, etc., it makes its various beeps and noises. I would like to not have this happen since I find it a little annoying and I'm sure those who have to work around me would like to have things quiet so they can concentrate on their work. Is there a way to accomplish turning off the beeps (while still being able to easily re-enable them), or am I out of luck?

Comment: Guess you're stuck needing earplugs! :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no software or hardware volume control on the Roomba.

You could probably put a potentiometer inline with the speaker wire to manually change the volume.  However, getting to the speaker is a bit of work.  But I believe is totally doable.  You just have to disassemble (and reassemble) lots of the robot.  This would make a great project, be sure to [submit](http://www.irobot.com/About-iRobot/STEM/Create-2/Submit-a-Project.aspx) it!

P.S. I just found this page (http://www.schneordesign.com/Avi/irobot/roomba_spk1.htm) on how to access the Roomba speaker.  The page is actually about how to fix a broken speaker, but there are step-by-step instructions on how to get to the speaker.  And once you are are there, you can cut a wire for no sound, or add in some resistance for a quieter sound.

Comment: I was afraid that this was the answer. If I do end up doing this, I will! But tbh, I may just tolerate it because getting things working is a priority at this point.

Comment: @Eric can't you barba... ahem mechanically obstruct the speaker? Or even destroy the cone via a needle? Come to think of it, molten silicone gets quite hard and not sticky at all so a seal of that should *possibly* be removable at a later date with the push of a thumb.

Answer (score 2):

Late late answer, but this is also the only thing that comes up when you Google this.
I ended up installing a 100 Ohm resistor on the speaker wire. It seems to be a good sweet spot for lowering the volume but still hearing it If you need to know it's location. 200 Ohm made it almost a whisper, for comparison.

I have a 690. I used this video https://youtu.be/s8K2gCzfTxE for taking it completely apart but stopped at the speaker.(don't Remove the circuit board)[image: 690 resistor install]

The image shows the resistor before sealing it in shrink tubing.

As shown, you can also just disconnect the connector if you want to silence it, but not cut any wires.

Comment: I for one think this is a fantastic answer. Welcome!